# How to select a color for each value in a foreach in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

With the code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
    \pgfmathparse{\i * 10-10}
 \draw[red!\pgfmathresult!blue, thick]
(0,\i * .2) -- (1,\i * .2)
;
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

one can index colors, but only "between" red and blue. How can I select, out of a list of arbitrary colors the items (they don't have to be 10, 3 will do, so for sake of concreteness, green, red, blue) and read them off in each value of my `\foreach` statement?

[image]

I tried to index them using a list of words, as stays in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66330/labeling-with-words-with-counter-using-lists) but TikZ doesn't display the colors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `\foreach \i/\c in {1/green, 2/red, 3/blue}` or `\foreach \c [count=\i] in {green, red, blue}`, which both yield the same result.

In the first example you separate the values and colors with a forward slash `/`. Since you have the consecutive integers 1, 2 and 3, you can use the `count` option, which in that case is more intuitive in my eyes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \c [count=\i] in {green, red, blue} {
    \pgfmathparse{\i * 10-10}
 \draw[\c, thick]
(0,\i * .2) -- (1,\i * .2)
;
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]